# Custom Grouping and Partitioning in Job Conf

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

AWS Job not accepting the configuration parameters for Custom Grouping and Custom Sorting.

conf3.setOutputValueGroupingComparator(StockKeyGroupingComparator.class);
 conf3.setOutputKeyComparatorClass(StockKeySortComparator.class);

I run the jar from the console.

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks,

Mahalakshmi

Comment: What do you mean by "not accepting"?

Comment: There is no effect of setting these configuration parameters in the job conf. That's what I meant.

Comment: Can you share the code which submit the job from this conf3 object you have created ?